# Jenksinfile fail next stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to fail next stage if previous one was failed but the one after should be running.

Can´t really give any code so I hope on that I can get some lead from you guys how I should achive this.

but for example

```
Stages{ 
   Stage{
      Stage that will fail
   }
   Stage{
      Stage that should fail if previous fail
   }
   Stage{
      Stage that should fail if previous fail
   }
   Stage{
      Stage that should run eitherway
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the only way, but it is one way it can work. By setting some environment variable switch that is then evaluated in a when block at the beginning of subsequent conditional stages. Subsequent stages here will not "fail", they will just be skipped due to when condition. The last stage doesn't have a when block so is carried out regardless.

```
// declarative

environment {
  FAIL = false
}

Stages{ 
  Stage('Stage that might fail') {
    steps {
      script {
        try {
          sh 'whatever happens that may cause this stage to fail'
        } catch (err) {
          echo err.getMessage()
          env.FAIL = true // Sets the variable to true which will be evaluated in when block on subsequent stages 
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  Stage('Stage that should fail if previous fail') {
    when {
      expression {
        return env.FAIL != "true" // note that even though FAIL was set as a boolean value the var is stored as a "string"
      }
    }
    steps {
      // do something
    }
  }
  
  Stage('Stage that should fail if previous fail') {
    when {
      expression {
        return env.FAIL != "true"
      }
    }
    steps {
      // do something
    }
  }
  
  Stage('Stage that should run either way') {
    // no when block = execute either way
    // do stuff
  }
}
```